# Javascript if function check

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have searched and found numerous discussions on this but none of the solutions seem to work.

Scenario:
 I have a central script which processes a complex calculator.  This calculator has over a 1000 separate calculators, each of which is called via a function.

Each of those functions is loaded dynamically based on user selection (keep overhead down  etc...)

So, core script is similar to this:

```
var m1 = 5;
var m2 = 8;


dynamicfunction1();
dynamicfunction2();

var m3 = m1 + m2;
```

The dynamic functions can change the values of m1 for example, depending on criteria (I'm keeping the example short).

So, I want to first check if the function exists before I run it, if not, ignore it.

So, I intended to have:

```
FncChk("dynamicfunction1");
FncChk("dynamicfunction2");
```

Below is an example where I have created one function, but tried to test 2 (clearly 1 doesn't exist).  The issue comes around window[] (applied rather than eval(); )I just don't seem to be able to get the string to translate into a function name to execute it.

```
function MonkeysEatBananas() {
    alert("Function triggered, Monkeys are eating bananas");
}

function FncChk(FuncName) {
    var fn = window[FuncName];
    alert(fn + "---> " + FuncName);

    if (typeof fn == "function" ){alert("Run function hetttre");}else{alert("Function "+FuncName+" not loaded");}
    }
}



FncChk("MinionsEatBananas");

FncChk("MonkeysEatBananas");
```

I can validate the function as a function by using an inline statement like:

```
if(  typeof MonkeysEatBananas == "function" ){alert("Run function here");}else{alert("Function "+FuncName+" not loaded");}
```

but not when I wrap it in a function for wider user and less code.  I just know I'm doing something stupid but I've killed hours on this, hence time to fire a flare!  Any kicks in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: Idk where to start. Why'd you tag jQuery?

Comment: Don't do this all in the global window space. Use properties of an object literal

Comment: and "function" !== \'function'\

Comment: Jquery tagged as would also accept isfunction example.  again wont work when wrapping in a function.

Comment: Although not what you're asking, if your calculator has only 1000 or so operations, and these are each a couple of lines of code, then you'll actually be *increasing* overheads by loading them dynamically (network overhead, server time, latency).  Just put them all in one js file and min it.

Comment: This: if(  typeof MonkeysEatBananas == \'function\' ){alert("Function Exists");}else{alert("Function does not exist");} Works   Whereas when I put it into a function.....  It doesn't

Comment: There are close to 800000 lines of calculation.  over 1000 calculators

Comment: this rather than window didn't work.  It all processes correctly until trying to apply within a function.  I thought the example was quite straightforward, maybe too simple.  Should I alter?

Comment: Thanks Jonas, changed.  I dynamically write JavaScript within PHP, sloppy copy/paste there, thanks for spot :)

Comment: @charlietfl  Do you have an example?  of how this helps define which functions are loaded or not loaded?

Comment: Exactly where is `MonkeysEatBananas` defined?  Is it defined against `window`?  (ie global) or is it in a namespace?  Or within doc.ready?

Comment: @freedomn-m  in the example it is in the same window.  and doesn't work.  I intended to get the function check to work here before I started passing dynamic content in for further validation.  It's an odd one.  There are loads of questions around this type of issue but if there is an answer out there, it's very well hidden.

Comment: Your code appears to work fine.  Have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/rcondrnt/ and see what I've not done that you're doing.

Comment: @freedomn-m  perfect, thank you.

Comment: @freedomn-m  can you put that as an answer and I will mark correct and close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window["functionName"]` directly, as long as the function is global.

To test if a function, use `typeof window["functionName"] == "function"` and to execute, just add `()`.

```js
function abc() { console.log("abc")}

function runFunc(f)
{
  var fn = window[f];
  //console.log(fn)
  if (typeof fn == "function") fn(); else console.log(f + " not found")
}

runFunc("abc");
runFunc("def");
```

The `jquery` version is pretty much the same:

```js
function abc() { console.log("abc")}

function runFunc(f)
{
  var fn = window[f];
  if ($.isFunction(fn)) fn(); else console.log(f + " not found")
}

runFunc("abc");
runFunc("def");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you use namespaces, you can do the same but just using the object instead of `window` (depending on how you implement namespaces, basic object example below):

```js
var calc = {};
calc.abc = function() { console.log("abc") }

calc.runFunc = function(f) {
  var fn = calc[f];
  if (typeof fn === "function") fn();
  else console.log(f + " not found")
}

calc.runFunc("abc");
calc.runFunc("def");

// global namespace (window) now only has 'calc' and not all the calc functions
console.log("window[abc] = " + window["abc"]);

// can also call directly
calc.abc();
```

Here's an alternative namespacing method using a self-executing function (or, if you're a stickler: Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE))

```js
var calc = (function() {

  var publicScope = {};

  //Public method
  publicScope.runFunc = function(f) {
    var fn = methods[f];
    if (typeof fn === "function") fn();
    else console.log(f + " not found")    
  };

  var methods = {}; 

  //Private method
  methods.abc = function () {
    console.log("abc");
  }

  //Return only the public parts
  return publicScope;
}());

calc.runFunc("abc");
calc.runFunc("def");

//cannot call directly (as they're private) (gives error)
calc.methods.abc();
```

Comment: Thanks @freedom-m  That is a great explanation.  I hope this thread who helps others, your answer is very comprehensive.  During searches all I could find were the odd one liners etc. rather than an actual working solution.  kudos :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the *in* operator:

```
if("func" in window) func();
```

and you may have a look at OOP, and dynamic function names are always a bad idea...

Comment: Thanks Jonas, that didn't work.  I'm looking to validate if it is a function within a simple function name.  So function IsItFunction(somefunctionnamecheck){ IF yes, execute, IF not function  ignore }